# XCode losing provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

I have two XCode projects the first is an iOS app the second a MacOS application. Whenever I build one the provisioning profile for the other is lost. So if I build the iOS app, when I then build the MacOS one I get an error because I use Map Kit. When I look at the provisioning profile in the build settings, the correct one is not even in the list in the menu. I have to double click on it in the Finder to reinstall it.

When I then go to build the iOS one the name of the provisioning profile I had selected has been replaced by a hex UUID and again the correct profile is missing from the list, I get a Code Signing Error and I have to reinstall them (development, ad hoc and App Store distribution ones) by double clicking on them in the finder.

As these two apps work in tandem and I alternate between building them on a daily basis this is becoming quite a pain..

I am using XCode 5.1.1, any suggestions gratefully received